# How to trim the spaces of the head of token list after using \tl_tail:N?

Tags: expl3

Here is a MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \tl_new:N \l_tmpc_tl
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {*~123}
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpb_tl
    {
      \tl_trim_spaces:n { \tl_tail:N \l_tmpa_tl }
    }
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpc_tl { \tl_tail:N \l_tmpa_tl }
  test \tl_use:N \l_tmpb_tl \par
  test \tl_use:N \l_tmpc_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

[image]

I found that `\tl_trim_spaces:n` didn't work. What I want is `test123`. And if I didn't use the `\tl_tail:N` then it worked.

I don't know how to solve this problem. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Short answer, replace with `\tl_trim_spaces:e`. (didn't write explanation.)

Comment: Actually `\tl_trim_spaces:e` doesn't exist.

Comment: @ZepingLee `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_trim_spaces:n { e }` now it does exist :)  (and it's expandable, contrary to `\tl_trim_spaces:N`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest in-place trimming with `\tl_trim_spaces:N`.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {*~123}
\tl_set:Nx \l_tmpb_tl { \tl_tail:N \l_tmpa_tl }
\tl_trim_spaces:N \l_tmpb_tl
% \tl_show:N \l_tmpb_tl
test \tl_use:N \l_tmpb_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much!